# How to fix error "CDbCommand ... SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064"

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I get this error when I use sql request

```
$query = "SELECT SUM ".$fields."
                  FROM tbl_report all_months
                  ".$joins."
                  WHERE all_months.date > '$from_date' 
                        AND all_months.date < '$to_date' GROUP BY fio";
```

but with operator Distinct it works

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ".$fields."
                  FROM tbl_report all_months
                  ".$joins."
                  WHERE all_months.date > '$from_date' 
                        AND all_months.date < '$to_date' GROUP BY fio";
```

Comment: `1064` Means that your SQL-query have syntax errors.

Comment: @Ghost, but how get a sum?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(fieldName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use open and close parenthesis on mysql [sum()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

```
$query = "SELECT SUM (".$fields.") AS result_value
```

Note: As hanky has said in the comments, it might not work as expected if the value of `$fields` contains comma separated list of column names.

If it is indeed, then you need to use `+` instead of `,`:

```
$fields = str_replace(',', '+', $fields);
```

Comment: Might also want to mention that `$fields` suggests that this could be a comma separated list of column names. `SUM` doesn't take those well

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yeah i was thinking about that variable name because its plural, the user didn't mention what `$fields` holds